# OVirt 4.2 Lost Connection To Nodes

Tags: redhat, kvm-virtualization, ovirt

I'm using OVirt version 4.2.3.8-1.el7 connected to 2 IBM PureFlex servers with 10 nodes (5+5) in total.

OVirt suddenly lost connection to all the nodes but the VMs in these nodes are working without a problem. I'm receiving the following error for all the nodes:

```
VDSM Node6 command GetCapabilitiesAsyncVDS failed: Message timeout which can be caused by communication issues
```

Nodes are reachable with SSH and I can do SSH to these nodes from OVirt management machine.

I've restarted OVirt management server once and it could connect to nodes for a while but the problem re-occurred after a while.

Can anyone help me how this can be fixed?

Answer (score 0):

I can only give you a check list:

- Can you ping the engine (management machine) from every node? Can you ping all nodes from the engine?
- Did you change anything?
  Have you issued any updated on the nodes or engines? Do you have engine backups?
- Did someone change the underlying network?
  Was IPv6 activated on your network recently? IPv6 is ok within VMs, but for the ovirt infrastructure (especially the version of oVirt you're running) this can cause problems.

Additionally you can try to reach out to the [very helpful oVirt community](https://lists.ovirt.org/).